# Keep names of subfolders in a list

Tags: python

In this a variable there is a folder called `main_folder`.
This folder has two folders:

`111`,`222`

I need to get the names of these folders in a list.

Tried this:

```
a = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\main_folder'
import os 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(a):
    print(dirs)
```

gives:

```
['111', '222'] # <--------------This only needed
[]
[]
```

How to keep only the first list and not the empty ones which I think describe the contents of these folders since they don't have folders.

Comment: If you just need the two top-level directories, why are you using os.walk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will do the job:

```
import os
def get_immediate_subdirectories(a_dir): ##a_dir is the path of the main folder
    return [name for name in os.listdir(a_dir) ## returns all the immediate subfolders
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(a_dir, name))] ## keeps checking the name + file is here
```

Calling Function:

```
get_immediate_subdirectories("Path")
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate just once via [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
import os

a = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\main_folder'
walker = os.walk(a)
res = next((dirs for _, dirs, _ in walker), [])
```

If necessary, you can continue iterating `walker` via additional `next` calls.